# scala - using asInstanceOf with Generics

Tags: scala, generics, casting, type-inference

I'm having compilation issues with generics. The code compiles fine when I use `asInstanceOf`. I want to get rid of `asInstanceOf`.

I saw some other questions related to the usage of `asInstanceOf`, but I didn't help me.

```
trait RoundRobin[R <: Resource, F[_] <: mutable.ListBuffer[_]] {
  self: RoundRobin[R, F] =>

  // some public functions

  private def overrideMutableResourceList(original: F[R], updated: F[R]): F[R] = {
    val tempPool = original.asInstanceOf[mutable.ListBuffer[R]]
    original.indices.foreach(i => {
      val e = updated(i).asInstanceOf[R]
      tempPool.update(i, e)
    })

    tempPool.asInstanceOf[F[R]]
  }
```

When I remove the `asInstanceOf` from `tempPool.asInstanceOf[F[R]]` I get the below error

```
[error] /Users/...../RoundRobin.scala:108: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : tempPool.type (with underlying type scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[R])
[error]  required: F[R]
[error]     tempPool
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (clustering/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Oct 3, 2017 2:53:34 AM
```

This issue happens also for the line `original.asInstanceOf[mutable.ListBuffer[R]]`

- What is the reason for this issue?
- How can I avoid using `asInstanceOf` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no relationship between `F[A]` and `ListBuffer[A]`, only that `∀A∃B F[A] <: ListBuffer[B]`. This is important:

```
type ConstLBInt[A] = ListBuffer[Int]
val x: RoundRobin[Resource, ConstLBInt] = ??? // Legal
// Tries to manipulate ListBuffer[Int]s as if they were ListBuffer[Resources]s
```

Change the declaration of your type to

```
trait RoundRobin[R <: Resource, F[A] <: mutable.ListBuffer[A]]
//                                !                        !
```

This forces `∀A F[A] <: ListBuffer[A]`, so that e.g. the `updated: F[R]` in `overrideMutableResourceList` is known to be a `ListBuffer[R]`.

There are probably other parts of the class that will be simplified by this.